# Trying to get fittext to work in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have the following code in my template page and I have registered jquery and fittext in my theme's `functions.php`. They are currently showing up in the footer as I set them to. I can set them up in either the header or the footer, but fittext just is not working where ever I place it. When I reduce the screen size the font is supposed to shrink but it doesn't. I am not sure why this is.

I have put up a very rough version of the site it basically just shows the fittext not working you can view it [here](http://www.austin.kitson.org/update/wordpress-1/?page_id=2) with the username:anders and password:reading61

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:Tech Basics
*/
?>
<?php get_header( 'tech' ); ?>

<div id="quote">
    <h1 id="fittext3">Sending you the techie! son you never had.</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fittext3").fitText();
    </script>
<div class="row mainContent">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <?php 
        $page_id = 10; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id from your site, which you can find by mousing over the link to edit that Page on the Manage Pages admin page. The id will be embedded in the query string of the URL, e.g. page.php?action=edit&post=123.

        $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. If you pass in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 ); ), WordPress will generate an error. By default, this will return an object.

        echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // echo the content and retain Wordpress filters such as paragraph tags. Origin from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_pagepost-and-no-paragraphs-problem
?>
    </div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**This seems to get it working however I know it isn't a proper technique, for some reason fittext wants the js right in the middle of the page can any one help with this.**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:Tech Basics
*/
?>
<?php get_header( 'tech' ); ?>

<div id="quote">
    <h1 id="fittext3">Sending you the techie! son you never had.</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fittext3").fitText();
    </script>
      <h2 id="fittext1">Welcome to Foundation</h2>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/austin.kitson.orgWP/wp-content/themes/git.austin.kitson.org/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fittext1").fitText();
        $("#fittext2").fitText(1.2);
        $("#fittext3").fitText(1.1, { minFontSize: 50, maxFontSize: '75px' });
    </script>
<div class="row mainContent">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <?php 
        $page_id = 10; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id from your site, which you can find by mousing over the link to edit that Page on the Manage Pages admin page. The id will be         embedded in the query string of the URL, e.g. page.php?action=edit&post=123.

        $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. If you pass in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 ); ), WordPress will generate an error. By default, this will return an object.

        echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // echo the content and retain Wordpress filters such as paragraph tags. Origin from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_pagepost-and-no-paragraphs-problem
?>
    </div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tested it in and have you checked the JavaScript console in any of them for errors?

Comment: And have you turned `WP_SCRIPT_DEBUG` on?

Comment: I have only checked it in safari, however I can get it working fine in a regular document just not in wordpress, umm do you have a resource for learning how to check the console, not to familiar with that

Comment: @kaiser No i havent, how to I do that?

Comment: Can you provide link to live example of the issue? Things like this are not trivial to reproduce from description alone.

Comment: [Debugging WordPress - the Codex How-To](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). _Hint: Always check the Codex first_.

Comment: @Rarst give me a few minutes and I can put it up

Comment: @AndersKitson -- Sorry,  I'm on Windows 7 so I'm not 100% familiar with how to call up Safari's console (perhaps ⌘ + J). Apple seems to have discontinued Safari for Windows.

Comment: @Rarst I have put it online now, hopefully you might have some insight.

Comment: I have added a link above to the live site, if anyone wants to see what I am having trouble with.

Comment: your fitText script is at the bottom of the page, when `fitText()` is called in the middle of the page, the function doesn't yet exist, so it's giving you an undefined error. jQuery stuff should typically be wrapped in a `jQuery(document).ready();` to avoid these errors, see the jQuery docs for proper usage.

Comment: @Milo ok I just wrapped it in document.ready, however I am still getting the same problem. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally, for some reason using the $ in my script just doesnt work so I had to use jQuery instead like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("#fittext3").fitText(1.8, { minFontSize: '12px', maxFontSize: '75px' });
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: WordPress jQuery by default is in [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). another option is to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, note the `$` in `function($)`. this lets you use the `$` as the jQuery object ref inside of `ready` instead of having to use `jQuery`

Comment: @Milo Cool that works too